# turn off bash variable substitution

Tags: linux, bash

```
function ctrace {
  echo "+ $@"
  "$@"
}

ctrace echo "hi"
```

How would I get this function to output (with quotes):

```
echo "hi"
```

In this version the quotes are lost `echo hi`...  Here is another example:

```
a=b
ctrace echo $a
```

This should output `echo $a` instead of `echo b`

Comment: Can this be done without modifying the calling line?  In other words, only modify the ctrace function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the function, but the caller.

In the first case the quotes are stripped out before the function gets the parameters.  In the second, `$a` substitution is done before it gets to the function.

Try:

```
ctrace 'echo "hi"'
ctrace 'echo $a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the string within single quotes

```
ctrace 'echo "hi"'
ctrace 'echo $a'
```