# Dealing with special characters in CLI11

Tags: c++, c++11, command-line-interface

I have code like the following

```
flags->add_option("--name", name_, "The name.")->required();
```

I want to be able to pass strings like "aa$p$aa" to the `--name` parameter. However, this does not seem to work with CLI11, and the name gets truncated to just "aa". I need to escape the `$` characters to properly read the strings. So `aa\$p\$aa` works fine, and I get the expected string ("aa$p$aa").

Changing the function to `add_flag()` does not work either.

Is there a way to be able to pass arbitrary strings to a parameter as with either function calls above?

Comment: If $ and \ and * are special to the shell then you are probably using Linux.  Window's command line thinks ^ and % are special.  The parameter substitution happens before your program is executed.  You could always put single quotes around the parameters but you have to escape the single quotes inside your parameters.  Here is a question about turning off all that stuff (no answers) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114878/disable-histexpand-and-variable-substitution

Comment: Here are some questions that might be duplicates of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617453/controlling-shell-command-line-wildcard-expansion-in-c-or-c  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209718/turn-off-bash-variable-substitution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operating system takes the command you type in and executes the given program, passing the parameters to it.

The interpolation, and the handling of `$` characters in typed-in commands is handled by your operating system as part of executing the typed-in command. Your compiled C++ program receives the transformed arguments, as parameters. Your C++ program has no means to control what has happened before it was even executed.